# trying to get all the external links on a website with importxml

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would really appreciate some advice here,

**this should work, but it doesn't:**

```
=IMPORTXML("www.michaelcropper.co.uk",
 "//a[not(contains(@href,‘www.michaelcropper.co.uk’))]/@href","en_US")
```

basiclly this xpath query isnt right:

```
//a[not(contains(@href, example.com))]/@href
```

and I really can't figure out why, any suggestion?

I have tried writing this in different ways and it did not help and also changed google sheets' location.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=importxml(url,"//@href[not(contains(.,'michaelcropper.co.uk'))]")
```

or with url in parameter

```
=transpose(importxml("https://www."&B1,"//@href[not(contains(.,'"&B1&"'))]"))
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thank u so much! is there a way i can use a location insted of a url and then drag the fourmla? for exsample: ```=importxml(B1,"//@href[not(contains(.,'B1'))]")``` (B1 contain a url). for some reason, when i drag the this fourmla only the first B1 in updated, but not the second one: ```=importxml(C1,"//@href[not(contains(.,'B1'))]")```

Comment: you can put in B1 for instance `michaelcropper.co.uk` and in C1 `=transpose(importxml("https://www."&B1,"//@href[not(contains(.,'"&B1&"'))]"))` then drag

Comment: thanks, but this ```=transpose(importxml("https://www."&B1,"//@href[not(contains(.,'"&B1&"'))]"))``` doesn't work

Comment: it works for me, I have added a screenshot